# 16 byte random string with increasing entropy

Tags: python, aes

I'm trying to generate a huge amount of random string of 16bytes with increasing entropy.
By increasing entropy I mean to increase the number of random character possibily selected, every 1000 generated string.
I want to store every string in a file, in a way that i can send every line to openssl for aes encryption (that's why 16byte).
That's my code. Is that right?

```
file = f=open('/root/randomGenString.txt', 'w')
for y in xrange(0,256):
        print "Range", y
        for x in xrange(0,1000):
                #print random.randint(0,y)
                stringa=''.join(chr(random.randint(0,y)) for z in xrange(0,16))
                file.write(stringa)
                file.write("\n")
file.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This almost does what you want, but it's not the best way of doing it.

Firstly, there's this thing about

```
file.write("\n")
```

Have you considered that `stringa` will naturally contain newlines? Since it will there's little point in delimiting it with newlines. Just drop that and use `file.read(16)` when opening it.

There's also that thing about `stringa` containing newlines. `\n` is automatically translated to `\r\n` on Windows for files opened in text mode. It's called *universal newlines* and it's a very useful feature. But it'll mess up your bytes. So you should open the file in binary mode.

While you're at it, look up `with statement python` on the webz.

Comment: I suggest you post the cleaned-up code.